# Using find & replace with regex to refactor a method call in Visual C++

Tags: regex, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I have loads of instances of code like:

```
throw CODBCException("Error!",GetHENV(),GetHDBC());
throw CODBCException(Msg,GetHENV(),GetHDBC());
```

I want to replace each with a utility method:
`throwException("Error!")` or `throwException(Msg)`

Is this something Visual C++ search/replace can do using a regex? I never used this feature before and I don't really know regex well either, but it would be pretty neat.

I'm only interested what comes up to the first comma e.g. `throw CODBCException("Error!",` so really I'm searching to replace `throw CODBCException(X,...)` with `throwException(X)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how generic you want the regex to be (eg. how close to the string examples you gave does the match have to be), but you use this for the find option:

```
throw[ \t]*CODBCException\({.*},[ \t]*GetHENV\(\),[ \t]*GetHDBC\(\)\);
```

and then use this for the replace with option:

```
throwException(\1);
```

In general, you can use the curly braces to specify a back-reference you want to replace, and use "\1", etc. to replace them.

Edit: Per updated question description, the following should be used for the find option:

```
throw[ \t]*CODBCException\({(".*")|([^,]+)},.*\);
```

Comment: Good point, I clarified my question but your answer does cover the exact case I would see 99% of the time.

Comment: In that case, it's even easier, I think.  Simply do "throw [\t]*CODBCException\({.*},.*\)", and use the same replace option, "throwException(\1)" (without quotes).

Comment: Escape the parentheses with "\" characters.  It doesn't show up in my edit text.  I updated the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: For some reason, that gives me an output like `throwException("error",GetHENV(),GetHDBC());` - the group is messing up. I had to tweak it to: `throw[ \t]*CODBCException\({[^,]+},.+\);` even though I know this would break if this would break on `throw CODBCException("test, case",...`

Comment: Good point.  The .* will match the commas, too.  I updated the find option.  This time, the first option for the case of stuff that's in parentheses.  Then another for the case of variable names (using [^,]+ like you suggested).